# Android-Toast.maketext not working

Tags: android, checkbox, toast

I totally new in Android. For example I create a check-box, the Toast.maketext did not work in AVD in eclipse even in VirtualBox. Can anyone tell me what wrong in my code. 
Thanks in advance.

```
cbxReading = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbxReading);
cbxReading.getOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (isChecked) {
        if (hobbies.contains("Reading")) {
            hobbies.add("Reading");
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Added Reading",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        } else {
            if (hobbies.contains("Reading")) {
                hobbies.remove("Reading");
               Toast.makeText(ctx, "Removed Reading",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: what does LogCat say about this?

Comment: Have you stepped through it with the debugger?  I think you're not getting to either Toast.

Comment: @ergwin logcat say  W/iinputconnectionwrapper(2440) ShowstatusIcon on inactive InputConnection. Before that 10 line E/LibEGL(1191): Called unimplemented OnpenGL ES API

Comment: @user1132457 so what i need to do with adb ? It was not working with both of check box I have

Comment: Are you sure `hobbies.contains("Reading")`?

Comment: what is your context that you are passing in your toast? just check it first. @user2705729

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Toast.makeText(ctx, "Here!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (isChecked) {
        if (hobbies.contains("Reading")) {
            hobbies.add("Reading");
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Added Reading",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        } else {
            if (hobbies.contains("Reading")) {
                hobbies.remove("Reading");
               Toast.makeText(ctx, "Removed Reading",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. It work but when i click on check box. It show up only Here!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `getOnCheckedChangeListener` use `setOnCheckedChangeListener` .